# AWS elastic transcorder or running ffmpeg on EC2 ? Which is cheaper?

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, encoding

I have an assignment to convert a large set of videos into ogg, webm and mp4, for different resolutions plus mobile etc, I am considering running transcoding job queues using ffmpeg or use elastic transcoder. (**Background info:** the source files are already on S3 and the web application is quite integrated into AWS SDK, and files get added daily, real time conversion not required)

I know using EC2 and ffmpeg will involve some dev time and effort, as opposed to just using the transcorder API. But if there is good cost saving...

Therefore I have two questions

1) AWS say charge is roughly $.015/minute of video(SD). My question is, is each output file charged separately. Docs say they support up to 30 outputs for the same job. But it not clear whether it is per minute of the job or per minute of each output format ($0.45/minute of video for 30 output formats then) ?

2) Does any one have experience using EC2 and ffmpeg in this use case? Is this cheaper than transcorder??

Last time I developed something of this nature, I did not factor in the I/O costs for EC2 and I/O ended up costing more than instance itself. Are there any code optimizations that I can do, to make it cheaper? (apart from using spot instances, Cheaper Regions etc).

Comment: Do you also count the time of your work to manage EC2 based operation? Did you make sure you pay the royalties to the encoder? ETS makes it easier for you to run such operation.

Comment: royalties are applicable if your country recognizes software patents, mine doesn't. Besides we are mostly sticking to royalty free open source codecs expect in few rare cases... I have not factored in the time yet, which is why i want to understand the other costs, and complexity involved..  ETS is of course easier, which I am aware of as i mentioned in the question, but if there is cost saving especially at scale i should consider EC2 atleast...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AWS Elastic Transcoding Service only supports MP4/H.264/AAC. It does not currently support WebM/VP8/Vorbis or Ogg/Theora/Vorbis (which are the other two container/video/audio combinations you're looking for).

As such, a custom ffmpeg installation is a requirement for the purpose of your *assignment*, but you can very quickly run astray of legal issues if you use the wrong combination of software libraries. It's a legal minefield of patent law issues.

Once you get past that, you need to figure out what you're looking for. Cheap & Slow vs. Fast & Expensive. Having built this very thing before, I would recommend nothing smaller than an EC2 XL instance. If you try to use a Micro or a Small, be prepared to spend hours and hours waiting around for the encoding to complete.

You'll also need to think about how to trigger the encodes on upload, if that's what you're going for. ETS doesn't do that — you have to trigger them manually.

**Update:** ElasticTranscoder now supports Webm VP8 & VP9, HLS, and a few other formats by default.

Comment: thanks a ton, I currently have a EC2 High Compute medium instance,  I am getting speeds for WebM (22-24fps) and ogv(170-180fps). I guess ETS is not a option, since WebM/VP8/Vorbis or Ogg/Theora/Vorbis are requirements. Perhaps once I iron out the issues, I can scale it up to a better instance..

Comment: regarding the legal issues, I guess it is a headache, but only for H.264/AAC right? Which as per my understanding MPEG group has made free, if the website does not charge for end users?

Comment: [MPEG-LA's PR for H.264 on the web](http://www.mpegla.com/Lists/MPEG%20LA%20News%20List/Attachments/74/n-10-08-26.pdf); [MPEG-LA's PR about Google and VP8](http://www.mpegla.com/Lists/MPEG%20LA%20News%20List/Attachments/88/n-13-03-07.pdf). As far as anyone can tell, Theora and Vorbis are patent-free, or the patents have expired. You also need to pay attention to the licenses of the ffmpeg components being used -- both for encoding as well as decoding. What if someone uploads an old Cinepack-encoded video in an AVI container? I can't confirm that the decoder (reader) software is GPL'd.

Comment: You can definitely build something that works and keeps you above-board when doing this kind of stuff, but you have to go into it with your eyes open and stay aware of what you're doing/using.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, Best if i leave it to the legal department, I got some additional complications as the countries where the application is being hosted and used, both do not recognize software patents in the first place, not sure how that impacts the licenses